# Fragment dynamic layout save ui changes screen orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, state

I am trying to maintain the ui changes so that when restarting the activity, the instance of my fragment become used with the changes of the buttons. So I found setRetainInstance(true) doesn't destroy the fragment object, however, the resulted view is destroyed. So I overrode onSaveInstance in the fragment class to save the ids of the resources that is called in the event handlers for setting it the next time the activity is created. The result was unexpected, at least for me:
1. The view of the fragment is destroyed when recreating the activity and the fragments instance become reattached to the new activity instance.
2. Event handlers become non-operational, so I don't know where is the problem.

Here is the code of the activity class:

```
package com.voicenoteinc.ticatactoy;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Tic_Fragment s;
        FragmentManager manager;
        String TAG_FRAGMENT = "tag_fragment";
        FragmentTransaction trans;
        boolean retained = true;
        String COLOR_ARRAY;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            manager = getFragmentManager();
            s = (Tic_Fragment) manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
            if(s == null){
                s = new Tic_Fragment();
                retained = false;
                trans = manager.beginTransaction();
                trans.add(R.id.fragment_container,s,TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

and Here is the code for the Fragment class:

```
package com.voicenoteinc.ticatactoy;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class Tic_Fragment extends Fragment {
    public Button bu1,bu2,bu3,bu4,bu5,bu6,bu7,bu8,bu9;
    int COLOR[] = new int[9];
    public String COLOR_KEY = "COLOR_KEY";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        for(int i =0; i<9;i++){
            COLOR[i] = R.color.granite;
        }
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tic_fragment,container,false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        for(int i =0; i<9;i++){
            COLOR[i] = R.color.granite;
        }
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            COLOR=savedInstanceState.getIntArray(COLOR_KEY);
            bu1.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[0]);
            bu2.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[1]);
            bu3.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[2]);
            bu4.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[3]);
            bu5.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[4]);
            bu6.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[5]);
            bu7.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[6]);
            bu8.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[7]);
            bu9.setBackgroundResource(COLOR[8]);
        }else{
            bu1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu1);
            bu2 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu2);
            bu3 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu3);
            bu4 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu4);
            bu5 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu5);
            bu6 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu6);
            bu7 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu7);
            bu8 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu8);
            bu9 = getView().findViewById(R.id.bu9);
        }
        eventhandlers();
    }

    public void eventhandlers(){
        bu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu1,1);
            }
        });
        bu2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu2,2);
            }
        });
        bu3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu3,3);
            }
        });
        bu4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu4,4);
            }
        });
        bu5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu5,5);
            }
        });
        bu6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu6,6);
            }
        });
        bu7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu7,7);
            }
        });
        bu8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu8,8);
            }
        });
        bu9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                display(bu9,9);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putIntArray(COLOR_KEY,COLOR);
    }
    public void display(Button bu, int i){
        int backgroundColor = R.color.greenery;
        bu.setBackgroundResource(backgroundColor);
    COLOR[i-1] = backgroundColor;
}
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

Thank ou for helping, and by the way I am new to using Fragments and Dynamic Layouts

Comment: **A small Edit: **So I overrode onSaveInstance in the fragment class to save the integer of the resource colors

Comment: No UI Restore was recognized